I need to disable INFO for nlog on Microsoft.* and System.* but it isn't working
I want to disable the output of "Info" and it seems like this should work, but it doesn't.  I a kind of new to NLog.

<!-- File Target for own log messages with extra web details using some ASP.NET core renderers -->
<target xsi:type="File" name="ownFile-web" fileName="c:\JBF Logging\${environment:INSTANCE_NAME}\${environment:INSTANCE_NAME}-nlog-AspNetCore-own-${shortdate}.log"
        layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId:whenEmpty=0}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}" />

<!-- Console Target for hosting lifetime messages to improve Docker / Visual Studio startup detection -->
<target xsi:type="Console" name="lifetimeConsole" layout="${MicrosoftConsoleLayout}" />

<!-- Exclude non-critical Microsoft logs -->
<logger name="Microsoft.*" minlevel="Warn" final="true" />

<!-- Skip non-critical System.Net.Http logs -->
<logger name="System.Net.Http.*" maxlevel="Warn" final="true" />

<!-- Log all other messages to allfile and ownFile-web -->
<logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="allfile" />


When troubleshooting NLog it is a good idea to enable throwConfigExceptions="true" and ensure the expected NLog.config-file is deployed. See also tutorial for setting NLog up for ASP.NET
